# mongodb find query with OR and AND

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following if query.

```
if(($version[0] == 1)||($version[1] > 6)||($version[2]>=14 && $version[1] == 6))   
{
  echo "true";
}
```

Now I want this query translated to a mongodb query.
In the mongo collection I have the following entry:

```
{
  "main_version" : 0,
  "sub_version" : 6,
  "build_version" : 14,
  "module" : "Co2",
  "active" : 1
}
```

When I try the following query I get a mongo error.

```
$where = array('$or' => array(
                array('main_version'=> (int)$version[0]),
                array('sub_version'=> array('$gt'=> (int)$version[1])),
                array('$and' =>  array('build_version' => array('$gte'=> (int)$version[2])),
                                  array('sub_version' => (int)$version[1]),
                     ),
                array('active'=> 1),
                ),
               );
```

Error:  Can't canonicalize query: BadValue and needs an array'

Does anybody know how to solve this query?

Comment: What programming lang are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using php

Comment: Well worked in php 6 years back but I think your $and operator should accept array of queries, something like array('$and' =>  array(array('build_version' => array('$gte'=> (int)$version[2])),
                                  array('sub_version' => (int)$version[1]))

I think 'and' accepts array as you are doing for 'or' opeartor, here you are passing the query instead of array.

Comment: Rahul,  Yes, the extra array was the sollution. tx

Comment: @RahulKumar add your solution as an answer so arjan can accept it and it will stand out more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, worked in php 6 years back but I think your $and operator should accept array of queries,

something like `array('$and' => array(array('build_version' => array('$gte'=> (int)$version[2])), array('sub_version' => (int)$version[1]))`

'and' accepts array as you are doing for 'or' opeartor, here you are passing the query instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the extra array was the sollution. tx